# 64 bit integer and 64 bit float homogeneous representation

Tags: algorithm, performance

Assume we have some sequence as input. For performance reasons we may want to convert it in homogeneous representation. And in order to transform it into homogeneous representation we are trying to convert it to same type. Here lets consider only 2 types in input - `int64` and `float64` (in my simple code I will use numpy and python; it is not the matter of this question - one may think only about 64-bit integer and 64-bit floats).

First we may try to cast everything to `float64`.
So we want something like so as input:

```py
31 1.2 -1234
```

be converted to `float64`. If we would have all `int64` we may left it unchanged ("already homogeneous"), or if something else was found we would return "not homogeneous". Pretty straightforward.

---

But here is the problem. Consider a bit modified input:

```py
31000000 1.2 -1234
```

Idea is clear - we need to check that our "caster" is able to handle large by absolute value `int64` properly:

```py
format(np.float64(31000000), '.0f')  # just convert to float64 and print
```

```py
'31000000'
```

Seems like not a problem at all. So lets go to the deal right away:

```py
im = np.iinfo(np.int64).max  # maximum of int64 type

format(np.float64(im), '.0f')
format(np.float64(im-100), '.0f')
```

```py
'9223372036854775808'
'9223372036854775808'
```

Now its really *undesired* - we lose some information which maybe needed. I.e. we want to preserve all the information provided in the input sequence.

So our `im` and `im-100` values cast to the same `float64` representation. The reason of this is clear - `float64` has only 53 significand of total 64 bits. That is why its precision enough to represent `log10(2^53) ~= 15.95` i.e. about all 16-length `int64` without any information loss. But `int64` type contains up to 19 digits.

> So we end up with about `[10^16; 10^19]` (more precisely `[10^log10(53); int64.max]`) range in which each `int64` may be represented with information loss.

#### Q: What decision in such situation should one made in order to represent `int64` and `float64` homogeneously.

I see several options for now:

1. <s>Just convert all `int64` range to `float64` and "forget" about possible information loss.</s>

   - Motivation here is "majority of input barely will be `> 10^16 int64` values".
   - *EDIT:* This clause was misleading. In clear formulation we don't consider such solutions (but left it for completeness).
2. Do not make such automatic conversions at all. Only if explicitly specified.

   - I.e. we agree with performance drawbacks. For *any* int-float arrays. Even with ones as in simplest 1st case.
3. Calculate threshold for performing conversion to `float64` without possible information loss. And use it while making casting decision. If `int64` above this threshold found - do not convert (return "not homogeneous").

   - We've already calculate this threshold. It is `log10(2^53)` rounded.
4. Create new type `"fint64"`. This is an exotic decision but I'm considering even this one for completeness.

   - Motivation here consists of 2 points. First one: it is frequent situation when user wants to store `int` and `float` types together. Second - is structure of `float64` type. I'm not quite understand why one will need `~308` digits value range if significand consists only of `~16` of them and other `~292` is itself a noise. So we might use one of `float64` exponent bits to indicate whether its `float` or `int` is stored here. But for `int64` it would be definitely drawback to lose 1 bit. Cause would reduce our integer range twice. But we would gain possibility freely store `int`s along with `float`s without any additional overhead.
   - **EDIT:** While my initial thinking of this was as "exotic" decision in fact it is just a variant of another solution alternative - composite type for our representation (see 5 clause). But need to add here that my 1st composition has definite drawback - losing some range for `float64` and for `int64`. What we rather do - is not to subtract 1 bit but add one bit which represents a flag for `int` or `float` type stored in following 64 bits.
5. As proposed @Brendan one may use composite type consists of "combination of 2 or more primitive types". So using additional primitives we may cover our "problem" range for int64 for example and get homogeneous representation in this "new" type.

**EDITs:**

1. Because here question arisen I need to try be very specific: Devised application in question do following thing - convert sequence of `int64` or `float64` to some homogeneous representation lossless if possible. The solutions are compared by performance (e.g. total excessive RAM needed for representation). That is all. No any other requirements is considered here (cause we should consider a problem in its minimal state - not writing whole application). Correspondingly algo that represents our data in homogeneous state lossless (we are sure we not lost any information) fits into our app.
2. I've decided to remove words "app" and "user" from question - it was also misleading.

Comment: Pick the one that fits your data requirements.

Comment: Have a look at [9.4. decimal — Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle not quite understand what requirements do you mean. Data requirements is `int64` or `float64` as input. Output should also work "around" this types.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes decimal and partly [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html) might be considered as solution here. Problem is this types are not so freely supported out of `python`. Even `numpy` has no corresponding `dtype`s.

Comment: I posted as comment, since 1) link-only answers are not real answers and 2) I'm not a Python guy.

Comment: *Data requirements is `int64` or `float64` as input.*  Those are not **requirements**.  Those are the storage options you appear to have chosen in your design. There is no correct answer given the lack of requirements for your data. Do you have to cover the full range a `float64` covers?  Do you need the ability to count accurately and fully items up to the maximum value of `int64`?   **That** is what you need to know to properly answer your question, and without addressing actual data requirements, your question is little more than [bikeshedding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding).

Comment: @AndrewHenle. Even if application would simply "repack" inputs and do not do any calculations at all - its still need to be able to handle to _all_ valid ranges for `int64` and `float64`. If it cannot and has some "data requirements" corresponding filter should be applied along with `int64` and `float64` type checking. But this would not be "`int64` or `float64` inputs" that user sees.

Comment: You are completely missing the point.  Your question is nothing more than a discussion of the differences between `int64` and `float64`.  Those **different types**  store **different data**.  What is this app **using** the data for?  That will decide the appropriate form to store it in, and having some esoteric discussion on different data formats (or maybe creating one on your own) won't change that at all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle in my question I deliberately explain one of the operations that application do (and for simplicity only one; as well as only `int64` `float64` types). In my previous comment I restate it again. And also determine valid input range not once.

Comment: Explaining your implementation isn't relevant to the requirements users have for data.  Explaining how a bicycle works doesn't mean anything to someone who has a **requirement** to deliver refrigerators.

Comment: @AndrewHenle will remind it if I ever would need to deal with "requirements to deliver refrigerators". And just in case - this question is exactly about "_how_ to implement". Besides in the beginning of the question: input is "sequence of ...". So _user_ provide us this as input which we want to.. etc.

Comment: Why not do what several programming languages do? That is, if there's a decimal point assume it's a float, otherwise assume it's an integer.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError if you have only 64 bit of data how would you determine is there decimal point or not? I mean if you have a sequence of  objects you need to store some metainfo about all of them as well. But if you managed to cast your data to homogeneous state you may store only metainfo for whole array at once. This is one of the "performance reasons" I stated in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing a data type there are 3 requirements:

- if values may have different signs
- needed precision
- needed range

Of course hardware doesn't provide a lot of types to choose from; so you'll need to select the next largest provided type. For example, if you want to store values ranging from 0 to 500 with 8 bits of precision; then hardware won't provide anything like that and you will need to use either 16-bit integer or 32-bit floating point.

When choosing a homogeneous representation there are 3 requirements:

- if values may have different signs; determined from the requirements from all of the original types being represented
- needed precision; determined from the requirements from all of the original types being represented
- needed range; determined from the requirements from all of the original types being represented

For example, if you have integers from -10 to +10000000000 you need a 35 bit integer type that doesn't exist so you'll use a 64-bit integer, and if you need floating point values from -2 to +2 with 31 bits of precision then you'll need a 33 bit floating point type that doesn't exist so you'll use a 64-bit floating point type; and from the requirements of these two original types you'll know that a homogeneous representation will need a sign flag, a 33 bit significand (with an implied bit), and a 1-bit exponent; which doesn't exist so you'll use a 64-bit floating point type as the homogeneous representation.

However; if you don't know anything about the requirements of the original data types (and only know that whatever the requirements were they led to the selection of a 64-bit integer type and a 64-bit floating point type), then you'll have to assume "worst cases". This leads to needing a homogeneous representation that has a sign flag, 62 bits of precision (plus an implied 1 bit) and an 8 bit exponent. Of course this 71 bit floating point type doesn't exist, so you need to select the next largest type.

Also note that sometimes there is no "next largest type" that hardware supports. When this happens you need to resort to "composed types" - a combination of 2 or more primitive types. This can include anything up to and including "big rational numbers" (numbers represented by 3 big integers in "numerator / divisor * (1 << exponent)" form).

Of course if the original types (the 64-bit integer type and 64-bit floating point type) were primitive types and your homogeneous representation needs to use a "composed type"; then your "*for performance reasons we may want to convert it in homogeneous representation*" assumption is likely to be false (it's likely that, for performance reasons, you want to avoid using a homogeneous representation).

In other words:

**If you don't know anything about the requirements of the original data types, it's likely that, for performance reasons, you want to avoid using a homogeneous representation.**

Now...

Let's rephrase your question as "How to deal with design failures (choosing the wrong types which don't meet requirements)?". There is only one answer, and that is to avoid the design failure. Run-time checks (e.g. throwing an exception if the conversion to the homogeneous representation caused precision loss) serve no purpose other than to notify developers of design failures.

Comment: Combination of primitive types is really the clause I missed from possible solutions. Also the "big rational numbers" is a stumbled me for now any additional info here will be appreciated.

Comment: Your explanation is different from my why single primitive type here won't be enough. But as for question itself why are you so deterministic about the answer? You also come to a conclusion that proposed my 1) not do (cause "then you'll have to assume "worst cases"") and propose to pick 2). But how about 3), 4) and proposed by you 5) - combination of primitive types? I.e. why 5 is definitely slower than 2? And why not use 3 at all? In fact 3 might be considered as 2.1 - if we succeed to convert - good. If not we will use 2.

Comment: Also minor question - why "-2 to 2 range" - should not be here "-2 to 1" for example (in order to get 2 bits range)?

Comment: @BeforeFlight: Assume a "big integer" is an array of primitive integer types capable of storing any unsigned integer that can fit in all available memory; but can't store any fractions. A "big rational" would have a sign flag, then three of these "big integers" (numerator, divisor and exponent); such that it can store numbers like `1/3` with perfect precision, and can store extremely large and extremely small numbers wasting lots of memory for trailing or leading zero bits. The "big rational" is the least limited representation possible - the only limit is available (virtual) memory.

Comment: @BeforeFlight: I don't say that your 1) won't do or propose 2); I say that it will either be fine (the homogeneous representation will meet requirements) or it will be a design failure (the homogeneous representation will not meet requirements). Your 3) is my "run-time check that exists to determine if there's a design failure", unless you're proposing a nonsensical "non-homogeneous homogeneous representation" that's equivalent to my "don't have a homogeneous representation". I also didn't say composed types are definitely slower, I said they're likely to be slower.

Comment: @BeforeFlight: I randomly selected the "-2 to +2 range" for an example because I wanted a 1 bit exponent, because I thought a floating point type with a 1 bit exponent is funny (and shows that "next largest type" can be very wasteful - e.g. wasting 7 bits of a 64-bit floating point type).

Comment: Because here same question arisen I need to try be very specific: Devised application in question do following thing - convert sequence of `int64` or `float64` to some homogeneous representation lossless. The solutions are compared by performance (e.g. total excessive RAM needed for representation). That is all. No any other requirements is considered here (cause we should consider a problem in its minimal state - not writing whole application). Correspondingly algo that represents our data in homogeneous state lossless (we are sure we not lost any information) fits into our app.

Comment: That is why my 3) will do and won't receive runtime error. As well as 1) definitely will fail here (conversion is not lossless; in fact I leave it for completeness only, I've strike it due to misleading). So we don't consider solutions that may lead to runtime errors (and how to deal around it - it's another question). I've also edited question to move closer to the deal - remove words "app" and "user" which definitely was not concern the problem itself.

Comment: @BeforeFlight: If all numbers stored in those 64 bit integers can be converted to 64-bit floating point without any precision loss; then it'd make more sense to use 64 bit floating point for those numbers in the first place; partly so that other programmers are aware of the restrictions (it's "self documenting"), and partly to the need for a homogeneous type (and the associated conversion/s, worries, and maintenance burden).

Comment: Agreed simple conversion need to be checked first. Seems like it should be composition of methods here. First we checking precision loss with simple convert to float (i.e. check bounds for int as in 3 clause) and if this fails -> devise some composition of primitive types. Now it's the only question for me left - should it be 1+64 bits (1bit added indication whether it float or int) or some other combination would perform better (i.e. 4 or 5 clause).

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very basic: use 64 bits floating point. Floating point *is* an approximation, and you will loose precision for many ints. But there are no uncertainties other than "might this originally have been integral" and "does the original value deviates more than 1.0".

I know of one non-standard floating point representation that would be more powerfull (to be found in the net). That might (or might not) help cover the ints.

The only way to have an exact int mapping, would be to reduce the int range, and guarantee (say) 60 bits ints to be precise, and the remaining range approximated by floating point. Floating point would have to be reduced too, either exponential range as mentioned, or precision (the mantissa).

Comment: Good point that `float` is already an approximation - I've not thought about it this way (even if it is obvious). Have also make some edits to the question.